How to extend tmux sessions when executing script is finished
On linux I do systemd-run --scope --user tmux to create a session that must long forever. Then I start executing scripts command like python. If executing continues many days and I close sessions, I can resume session by tmux attach -t 0.
But if the script stopped executing, there is a short time when I can resume session and read final logs, then sessions is closed and I can not see it on tmux list-sessions.
How to disable closing sessions?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Maybe I'm missing something but why would the tmux session close on its own if there's a running shell? Are you detaching from the session correctly using Ctrl +B / D?

@Community I need to stop closing tmux session by itself. I entered tmux session, then detached and closed windows terminal. But session still exists. Then I connect back to the server and I want to see tmux session still running. I do, but only when there are executing scripts on sessions still running (like python). If scripts stopped executing, then in some hours tmux will close session.

@kos why would the tmux session close on its own if there's a running shell - I don't know. So I run tmux, run script there (python), detach session, close terminal. Then open terminal again and can see tmux session only if it's still running python script. If not, it will close session in some hours.

How are you running the script? If the script is replacing the shell (e.g. when using exec /path/to/script), then the tmux session will close on its own when the script has finished executing. I mean, it's a bit far-fetched, but I personally don't have a more plausible explanation right now. My sessions stay alive forever unless I close them or run tmux kill-server
